Is $\mathrm{Vect}(k)$ the Yoneda embedding of B$k^+$?
For $k$ a field, I'm considering the one-object category B$k^+$ whose morphisms are the elements of the additive group of $k$. Then, is the category of vector spaces over $k$ the same as the Yoneda embedding / free cocompletion of B$k^+$?
This is why I think so. If we restrict to the full subcategory consisting of copies of the one representable, then I can't think of what differentiates this category from $\mathrm{Vect}(k)$. So the question is if there are any nontrivial colimits we can take that give us objects that don't correspond to a coproduct of copies of the representable. I don't think this is the case, because there's only one object in B$k^+$ to begin with -- how are we going to get colimits that aren't just copies of this one object? But of course I don't know what a precise version of this looks like.
On the other hand, this is why I don't think so. This description of $\mathrm{Vect}(k)$ is so short and nice that I'd expect to see it somewhere. In particular it says a representation of a group $G$ is a profunctor B$G \nrightarrow k$, which is just really nice. So the fact that this I can't find this framing anywhere makes me think it's just wrong.

No. If $G$ is a group then the category of presheaves on $BG$ is the category of $G^{op}$-sets, which is equivalent to the category of $G$-sets since every group is canonically isomorphic to its opposite, so here we get the category of $k^{+}$-sets.
$Bk^{+}$ doesn't know anything about the multiplication on $k$ so there's no hope for it to recover the category of $k$-vector spaces; there are non-isomorphic fields with isomorphic underlying additive groups, for example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.
If we instead work with $\text{Ab}$-enriched categories, we can consider $Bk$ as an $\text{Ab}$-enriched category with one object (here composition is the multiplication on $k$, and the addition is part of the enriched structure), and then the category of $\text{Ab}$-enriched presheaves on $Bk$ is the category of $k$-vector spaces. More generally, a one-object $\text{Ab}$-enriched category is $BR$ where $R$ is a ring, and then the category of $\text{Ab}$-enriched presheaves on $BR$ is the category of right $R$-modules.

how are we going to get colimits that aren't just copies of this one object? But of course I don't know what a precise version of this looks like.

You aren't thinking about the morphisms. The category of $G$-sets is the free cocompletion of $BG$, and not every $G$-set is a coproduct of copies of the representable one (which is the free $G$-set $G$), because groups have actions which are not free. But every $G$-set is a quotient of such a coproduct (exercise).

Sorry for hijacking this comment section (you don't have to answer), but since you are using that (common) notation here, do you think it is really necessary to distinguish notation-wise between $G$ and $BG$ for a monoid $G$? For example, in my book I always just write "... a monoid, considered as a one-object category", or I just leave it implicit. Will this be a disadvantage in any way? Maybe it is even the other way round since $BG$ already stands for a topological space (or an algebraic stack, even)? So I would rather not overload this notation. Similarly, ...

... why don't category theorists distinguish notation-wise between a preorder and the corresponding thin category (which, by the way, I am perfectly fine with)? Isn't this the same pattern?

I tend to think of $\mathbf{B}$ as a delooping operation that turns something "discrete" (like a group) into something more "like a space" (a topological space, a groupoid, a category...), not just notation. In particular it can be meaningfully iterated, whereas I don't think it makes sense to view a preorder as a category "twice". Also, a monoid can also be seen as a discrete monoidal category, so the notation may help avoid ambiguity.

Thank you for the comment, @NaïmFavier. I almost didn't see it because you didn't tag me. And sorry again Qiaochu for hijacking!

Never heard of G-sets before, and in hindsight it makes sense that the multiplication matters. Very happy you mentioned how if we change the base of enrichment to Ab we can still get Vect(k) this way; excellent answer!

@Martin: I agree with Naïm, FWIW. The fact that $B$ can be iterated is a sign that it is a meaningful operation that one should notate. $G$ and $BG$ exist at different categorical levels: $G$ is a set (a "monoidal set," if you like) so it is $0$-categorical, and $BG$ is a category so it is $1$-categorical. $G$ lives in a category (the category of groups) while $BG$ lives in a $2$-category (the $2$-category of groupoids, or categories). And so forth. The situation with posets is not the same pattern.
